# Interop.Excel - using output.,Rows[i].Delete() is shifting the rows up so that the most recent shifted row is not checked by for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, excel-interop

```
public void deleteInvalidEmployees(string path)
{
    Application app = new Application();
    Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(path);
    Worksheet output = wb.ActiveSheet;
    Range range = output.UsedRange;
    var LastRow = output.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

    for (int i = 2; i <= LastRow; i++)
    {
        bool containsLetters = false;
        string value = Convert.ToString(output.Cells[i, 2].Value);

        if (value != null && value != "")
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(value.ToUpper(), "[A-Z]"))
            {       
                Console.WriteLine("Contains letters for row " + i);     
                containsLetters = true;
            }
        }

        if (value == "" || containsLetters == true || value == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deleting empty row " + i);
            output.Rows[i].Delete();       
        }
    }

    wb.Save();
    wb.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```

As above I'm just doing a simple deletion of a row, but the problem is after it deletes the row It shifts the rows up ( which I want ) however this means that the most recent shifted row is skipped by the Forloop. For example If row 2000 is deleted then row 2001 gets shifted up to the position of row 2000, so the for loop gets incremented and then checks the 'new' row 2001 which means the 'old' row that got shifted up to position 2000 is skipped.

My first obvious solution was to decrement i whenever a deletion happens so that the current i position is rechecked with the new row, however this doesn't work.

Comment: You tagged this as ASP.NET. What does this have to do with ASP.NET? Are you using Excel Interop from your ASP.NET application?

Comment: Why does decrementing i not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: If you decrement `i`, you should also decrement `LastRow` or change the for-loop to check `output.UsedRange.Rows.Count` every time.

Comment: you can delete from last to 2, will overcome this.

Comment: Yeah I am using Excel Interop from my.NET application. Also when I decrement i it gets to row number 3659 and it stays there, constantly looping at 3659 and I have no clue why

Comment: @HHLV how can I change the for-loop to check  output.UsedRange.Rows.Count mid way through the loop?

Comment: Sorry I'm being stupid, You were right, decrementing LastRow fixed the issue, How do I upvote answers here? I'm pretty new

Comment: @Renjinator I didn't ask if you were using it from a .NET application. I asked if you were using it from ASP.NET? And I asked why you tagged this as ASP.NET. Can you please answer those questions? And remember to use the @ syntax to notify us of responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea to decrement `i` was good, but you should also decrement `LastRow` to prevent an IndexOutOfRangeException.

```
output.Rows[i].Delete();
i--;
LastRow--;
```

Instead of decrementing `LastRow` each time, you can check the row count directly in your for-loop.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= output.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
```

And even better, as zhiven suggested, you can reverse your loop. Then you don't have to update `i` on every deletion and you are sure to check every row.

```
for (int i = output.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i >= 2; i--)
```